# Passing multipart/form-data parameters to RESTful webservice using Spring-Integration

Tags: spring-integration

I am using Spring Integration in my project. I have RESTful webservice of type POST which accepts multipart/form-data types. I know that `int-http:outbound-gateway` can be used to execute the webservice.

But I don't know about passing the file types(multipart/form-data) to a Message and using them in the `int-http:outbound-gateway`.

To get an idea, the following is the screen print of the POSTMAN client where in the multipart/form-data type parameters are passed.
[image]

I want to pass the parameters in the same way to `int-http:outbound-gateway` by incorporating them in the Message. Any ideas on how to achieve the desired functionality? Please let me know if you require any additional info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler` has this code:

```
else if (content instanceof Map) {
        // We need to check separately for MULTIPART as well as URLENCODED simply because
        // MultiValueMap<Object, Object> is actually valid content for serialization
        if (this.isFormData((Map<Object, ?>) content)) {
            if (this.isMultipart((Map<String, ?>) content)) {
                contentType = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA;
            }
            else {
                contentType = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED;
            }
        }
    }
```

Therefor what you need is just a `Map<String, ?>` which fully reflect that HTTP form.

The [Multipart Http Sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/intermediate/multipart-http) can help you as well.